# How do I resolve the QuickBooks SDK Error: "Account needed for the discount"?

Tags: quickbooks

When using the QBSDK IReceivePaymentAdd Request, I keep hitting this error and the Payment is not created!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

1. Open Customers --> Receive Payments
2. Select 'Discounts And Credits'
3. Then populate the 'Discount Account' field